# Set Date and Time in a Private Network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I have created a private network using geth in **ubuntu**, but it takes date & time from the system on which it runs. So if the system date of the master node is changed, it affects syncing on the slave nodes.

**genesis.json**

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": id,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance": 
"111111111"},
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {"balance": "222222222"}
},
"coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
"difficulty" : "0x0",
"extraData"  : "",
"gasLimit"   : "9000000000",
"nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash"    : 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp"  : "0x00"
 }
```

Comment: Can you add some info on your setup? What OS are you using? Are you running all Geth instances directly on your machine or do you have VM or containers? Do you already have an NTP client running on this machine?

Comment: Geth instances are executed directly on machine with geth command and I'm not using NTP client.

Comment: can you provide the other infos? OS at least and if you are running VMs nor Docker. Thanks.

Comment: I mean assuming all your nodes are running on the same machine, I can't see why each node don't have the same date and time. So the only way I see is that either you have multiple machines or VM/container context

Comment: Private network is running on Ubuntu.18. Each machine holds one node, meaning nodes are running on separate machines. Currently I am not running VMs/Docker. But I am planning to use Docker since it will be useful for users to setup the environment.

Comment: Ok, so yes your machines are maybe not in sync on the time. Using a NTP client will help.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, as per your suggestion I made NTP server setup on mining node. But  still if user changes system date manually,  there will be same issues... right? Private blockchain considers system date. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No you are right.